# Consulta em duas tabelas

Tags: sql

Bom, como faço uma consulta em duas tabelas em sql?
Por exemplo, tenho uma tabela **Empresa** com os campos **id**,**razaosocial**, e **cnpj**. Tenho também uma outra tabela, **Filial** com os campos **id**,**endereco**,**empresa_id**.
Quero fazer um select da primeira tabela usando id, cnpj e um select da segunda tabela usando apenas o endereco.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá!

Basta fazer um join pela chave em comum nas duas tabelas. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
SELECT Empresa.id, Empresa.cnpj, Filial.endereco FROM Empresa INNER JOIN Filial on Empresa.id=Filial.empresa_id
```

Neste caso, você só irá trazer os resultados dos ids que forem comum na tabela Empresa e Filial. Caso queira retornar todos os ids da tabela Empresa, substitua **INNER JOIN** por **LEFT JOIN**.